# Python 3 How to workaround urllib.parse.urlencode missing quote_via in Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.4, urllib, urlencode

I have created a Python script on a machine running Python 3.5.2. Now I want to run it on another computer running Python 3.4.2 and I do not have the possibility to upgrade Python there.
My problem is that I used

```
urllib.parse.urlencode(dict, safe='/', quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)
```

The quote_via option is obviously not available in Python 3.4.2, so I get an error

```
TypeError: urlencode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quote_via'
```

I need to urlencode the dictionary `dict` here, using `quote()` only not `quote_plus()`, which is the default in both 3.4 and 3.5. However, only 3.5 seems to have a possibility to override the default.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your own `urlencode()` function. The [`urllib.parse.urlencode()` library function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L819-L897) consists mostly of tests to ensure that both `bytes` and `str` objects can be handled, as well as to handle the `doseq` flag.

Otherwise, it is little more than a loop encoding both the key and the value of each pair, adding `=` between them and concatenating all such pairs with `&`. Implement the same loop for your inputs, and hard-code the variant you need.

You can replicate your specific behaviour with:

```
'&'.join(['{}={}'.format(quote(k, safe='/'), quote(v, safe='/'))
          for k, v in dict.items()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirty hack approach :)

```
import urllib.parse
import sys
major, minor, _, _, _ = sys.version_info
if major == 3 and minor < 5:
    urllib.parse.quote_plus = urllib.parse.quote
```

Upd: slightly less dirty:

```
class MonkeyPatchQuote(object):
    def __init__(self):
        major, minor, _, _, _ = sys.version_info
        self.should_patch = major == 3 and minor < 5

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.should_patch:
            self.original_handler = urllib.parse.quote_plus
            urllib.parse.quote_plus = urllib.parse.quote

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        if self.should_patch:
            urllib.parse.quote_plus = self.original_handler
```

Comment: :-) Nice one. But I am not sure, if I used `quote_plus` elsewhere. So, this might be risky. However thank you, too.

Comment: This would be a global change, *and* you didn't save a reference to the old version to restore.